# InitializeComponent( ) does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I just open my framework after only 2 days of not touching it, and when I tried to run it and it returns `error` as shown below.

[EditContactPage.xaml.cs Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckio5.png)

Coding EditContactPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Contacts.Maui.Models;
using Contact = Contacts.Maui.Models.Contact;

namespace Contacts.Maui.Views;

[QueryProperty(nameof(ContactId), "Id")]

public partial class EditContactPage : ContentPage
{
    private Contact contact;

    public EditContactPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //  Navigate back to main page.
    //  void btnCancel_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    //  {
    //       Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ContactsPage)}");
    //       Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    //   }

    // property
    public string ContactId
    {
        // value of ContactId
        set
        {
            contact = ContactRepository.GetContactById(int.Parse(value));
            //lblName.Text = contact.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I remembered the last time I updated this project, it was still working fine. Am I missing something? I just do not understand how to wrapped my head around the `InitializeComponent()` function and where could I find its origin.

Edited: included EditContactPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Contacts.Maui.Views.EditContactPage"
                 Title="Edit Contact">
        <!--<VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label
                x:Name="lblName"
                Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" Clicked="btnCancel_Clicked" ></Button>
        </VerticalStackLayout>-->

        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="10,10,10,0">

            <Border Padding="10,0,0,0" HeightRequest="60">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Name" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
                    <Entry
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        WidthRequest="200">
                    </Entry>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Border>

            <Border Padding="10,0,0,0" HeightRequest="60">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Email" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
                    <Entry
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        WidthRequest="200">
                    </Entry>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Border>

            <Border Padding="10,0,0,0" HeightRequest="60">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Phone" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
                    <Entry
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        WidthRequest="200">
                    </Entry>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Border>

            <Border Padding="10,0,0,0" HeightRequest="60">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Address" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
                    <Entry
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HeightRequest="10"
                        WidthRequest="200">
                    </Entry>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Border>

        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

Comment: clean solution and/or delete your bin/obj folders

Comment: Did you changed a namespace? The `InitializeComponent()` is generated from the xaml file. This is where the controls/layout components are generated. That's why your class is a `partial class`. They are merged on compile.

Comment: Please show the corresponding XAML, or at least the root of it

Comment: I have included the corresponding xaml file.

Comment: For this error, you can refer to this issue on GitHub: [CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2863). It provides many solutions for this error.

Comment: Your screenshot shows an Intellisense error. Did you try build, to see if that fixes it? Given that it was working before, Jason’s suggestion is next to try. I would also look at any build errors, even if not related. There is always the possibility that you accidentally touched keyboard and added a character somewhere. I’ve done that. Best case, you have a recent source backup. Download source to a new folder, see if build works there.

Comment: I think thats the best solution. I just git clone my repo and redo it again (carefully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ToolmakerSteve said that:

> Best case, you have a recent source backup. Download source to a new
> folder, see if build works there.

If it doesn't work, then you can try Jason’s suggestion(clean solution and/or delete your bin/obj folders).

For more things about this error, you can see this issue on GitHub: [CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2863).